# Custom post type and google visibility

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a WordPress site that uses custom post types. However, the custom post types are not being recognized by google. It's like the custom post type is a box full of our original content that google can't see inside of it seems. What can I do to change this?

Comment: How are you registering your post type?

Comment: If you have an XML site map. Make sure your custom post type is part of it, and then tell google to index your sitemap again.

Comment: I do have the custom post type selected in the xml sitemap generator.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [WordPress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). It has a "Titles & Metas" section which allows you to define the SEO title and descriptions for custom post type articles, archives, and allows you to no-index an entire post type if wanted.

Comment: I am using that seo plugin and utilizing those features.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your sitemap, I searched for an element in your sitemap and googles returns me the exact page, http://lmgtfy.com/?q=gooutlocal+crush (Sitemap URL where it is referenced http://gooutlocal.com/sitemap-pt-bar-2015-02.xml). This looks like you haven't regenerated your sitemap after adding new content.

Comment: Ok I can do that but I don't think even the older stuff is being seen either...

Comment: Yes it is, click on the search link, it will show results for your site. Just remember this changes won't

Comment: ok I set it to update daily. Hopefully that does the trick. My adsense campaign was denied because of no content and that the site wasn't searchable...

Comment: This is your complete sitemap: http://gooutlocal.com/sitemap.xml It should be a good exercise to review it, and verify that all your content is there. If not, verify with your plugin that it is exporting all your content.  Remember if an answer helped you, mark it as Accepted. Will help you and the person that posted the answer.

Comment: The sitemap is totally fubar. It's not recognizing individual posts. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with not recognising individual posts?